# fabric.js on node - rotation (setAngle) changes position of object

Tags: node.js, svg, rotation, fabricjs, angle

I hav an app that creates a canvas in the browser and rendering on the server with Fabric.js under Node.

Object types of text and bitmap images rotate correctly.  "Path-group" shapes and SVG images rotate incorrectly.  "Path-group" shapes and SVG images appear to rotate on it's xy coords rather than on its center.

How do I force "Path-group" shapes and SVG images to rotate by the center.  Do I have set the angle for each path?

Comment: Before rotation 
 top: 509.25984990619145,\n left: 509.25984990619145
After rotation
 top: 55661.94786228961,\n left: -22335.731526155047
 
Code that cases this;
 tmpImage.setAngle(key.angle);

 Where key.angle is 45 and tmpImage is a grouped SVG

Answer (score 0):

To resolve, I set the rotation and scale separately instead of in a config object.

Setting origin to center, rotating object, setting origin back to top left then scaling resolves the issue.